# Sqlite EF global lock write

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, locking

I have an Sqlite database mapped in an Entity Framework context.

I write on this database from several threads (bad idea, i know). However i tried using a global lock for my application like this:

```
partial class MyDataContext : ObjectContext
{
    public new int SaveChanges()
    {
        lock (GlobalWriteLock.Lock)
        {
            try
            {
                int result = base.SaveChanges();
                Log.InfoFormat("fff Save changes performed for {0} entries", result);
                return result;
            }
            catch (UpdateException e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Still, i get the database file locked exception all the way down from sqlite itself. How can this be possible?

The only explanation I can see is that the base.SaveChanges method returns before the database gets unlocked and continues work asynchronously after returning.

Is this the case? If yes, how can I overcome this issue?

Note: My commits are usually updates of 1-100 entries and/or inserts of about 1-100 entries at a time.